# Get variable from base of view model in c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to grab a variable that is down the tree of the main view model.

```
public ActionResult Index(){
    MainViewModel vm = MainViewModel();
    string variable = {vm}SubViewModel.link;
    try{
       // Content here
    }
    catch{
    }
    return View(vm);
}
```

When I hover over vm, it has a "base" at the top (with the rest of the variables of the view model underneath) which leads me to the partial that holds the variable I need. How do I grab that variable? ( trying to get link from SubViewModel)

Comment: Please define SubViewModel, as in a property of the main VM, or a parent class?

Comment: like public class MainViewModel : SubViewModel

Comment: have you try to `vm.link`?

Comment: I did but it brings back a null value, but in the base it brings back the value i need. or at least shows the value

Comment: then show us complete code of your `MainViewModel` and `SubViewModel`

Comment: did you want the other classes/view models with it?

Comment: we want exactly `MainViewModel` and `SubViewModel` classes

Comment: @Keith this question needs to provide a [mcve].  Is the line `MainViewModel vm = MainViewModel();` missing the `new` keyword? Does `string variable = {vm}SubViewModel.link;` compile?